# C# Access class in program.cs from a Form Button

Tags: c#, forms, class

I have the current class in my program.cs

```
class valor
{
      private static double valuee;

      public static double Valor
      {
          get { return valuee; }
          set { valuee = value; }
      }
 }
```

And I want to use the set accessor from the properties.

Here's my form.cs:

```
private void dValor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double valor = Convert.ToDouble(dValor.Text); 
}
```

I want to get the .text from the TextBox and then store it in the class `valor` from the program.cs

What's the best way to make the access to the `valor` class?

Comment: You need to create a valor object and access it with `valor.value;` the class should be marked explicitly as `public` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of the `valor` in your `private void dValor_TextChanged` method or in the file that method resides depending on the access you want.

```
valor myValor = new valor();
```

Then you should simply be able to set that value to your `myValor` object.

```
myValor.Valor = Convert.ToDouble(dValor.Text);
```

And as said in a comment in reply to your question your valor class should be public.

```
public class valor
```

Comment: Error CS0176 Member 'Program.valor.Valor' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: I did `Program.valor dvalor = new Program.valor();
            dvalor.Valor =  Convert.ToDouble(dValor.Text);`

Comment: as I cannot acess `valor` with just `valor myValor`

Comment: Did you make valor a `public` class?

Comment: Yes I actually did

Comment: Okay so why is the `Valor` property static?

Comment: Ops, problem solved it was that Valor was static by mistake